# Last Nth Day in click house

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I use above condition in mysql to extract last 7 day date. how it works in clickhouse ?? I tried looking for it in click house docs but found nothing

```
   where date(created_at) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: note that by using `date(created_at)` you can't take advantage of an index on created_at; for that you need `where created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY and created_at < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY` (assuming created_at is a datetime or timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/special-data-types/interval/) shows, Clickhouse supports interval syntax (similar to other databases such as MySQL and Postgres).

We can rewrite your MySQL `WHERE` clause in Clickhouse as follows:

```sql
WHERE toDate(created_at) = toDate(now()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: looks like `toDate(now())` could be `today()`